# Ataque hacker ao painel do site

Tags: wordpress, segurança, plugin-wordpress, back-end

Instalei o plugin Wordfence e todos os dias recebo relatório de ataques hacker ao wp-admin/painel do site.

Resolvi mudar o endereço do admin com o plugin Protect WP-Admin, tipo assim: site.com.br/Cmr21VNW, me parece ser impossível de descobrir esse endereço mas continua chegando alertas de tentativas de acesso, menos alertas mas continua chegando.

Existe alguma maneira de tentar logar via URL?
Como será que foi descoberto o novo endereço?
Como impedir isso?

Obrigado pela atenção de todos.

Comment: Isso é normal. Hoje e dia existem robôs de ataque percorrendo toda web em busca vulnerabilidades para serem exploradas.

Comment: É por isso que a sua senha tem que ser bem forte. Caracteres especiais, letras maiúsculas, etc.

Comment: Realmente pelo relatório que Wordfence apresenta me parece que não é algo manual mesmo, porém não consigo entender como o "robô" achou a pasta de login que foi renomeada.

Comment: Veja se o seu servidor publica arquivos de auxilio a engines de busca. Tipo `sitemap` ou `robot.txt`. Ex: [https://www.google.com.br/robots.txt](https://www.google.com.br/robots.txt)

Comment: Meu robots.txt está assim:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-content
Allow: /wp-content/uploads
Disallow: /wp-admin

Mas não aponta o endereço novo do back-end do site.

Comment: De alguma forma a estrutura está sendo publicada. Dê uma olhada se tem atividade na porta TCP 389. 
Outra coisa, eu li que você usa IP dinâmico, você também usa DNS Dinâmico? Alguns DDNS's forçam a publicação da estrutura de diretório.

Comment: Não uso DNS dinâmico meu host é Locaweb, só meu meu IP de conexão é dinâmico. Realmente como disse "de alguma forma a estrutura está sendo publicada"  o plugin que usei não muda o nome da pasta wp-admin dentro do host mas apenas a url, se digitar wp-admin ou mesmo dominio.com.br//wp-login.php não abre o formulário de login. Me parece que é um ataque direto sem tentar acessar o form, só não sei qual o endereço usado pois continua chegando alertas de tentativas de acesso. Seria melhor mudar realmente o nome da pasta no host, talvez funcionasse melhor mas não sei o Wordpress aceita essa mudança.

Comment: Realmente no Wordpress não dá para mudar o caminho da pasta wp-admin somente a url. De qualquer forma procure por tráfego de dados na porta TCP 389 essa porta é padrão em todos os OS para publicação de serviços de diretórios distribuídos.

Answer (score 2):

você já pensou em restringir o acesso do site apenas para determinados IPs? Segue um tutorial de como fazer isso pelo arquivo .htaccess, o código é o seguinte:

```
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName &quot;Controle de Acesso Administrativo do WordPress&quot;
AuthType Basic
<LIMIT GET>
order deny,allow
deny from all
# whitelist IP de Asllan Maciel
allow from xx.xx.xx.xxx
# whitelist IP de Fulano de Tal
allow from xx.xx.xx.xxx
# whitelist IP de Beltrano
allow from xx.xx.xx.xxx
</LIMIT>
```

Fonte: http://www.wp24horas.com.br/tutoriais/proteja-wp-admin-wordpress-limitando-acesso-no-htaccess

Comment: Achei interessante a dica me parece que resolveria mas meu IP de conexão é dinâmico. Ai para mim também não funcionaria mas quem usa IP fixo de conexão é uma boa. Obrigado.